Mount LUKS partition in Windows on the same disk
I mostly use Linux on my dual-boot laptop (single drive), but still require Windows for work. Therefore all files are stored on the Linux system on a LUKS encrypted partition.
It would be handy if I could access the files from Windows straight away, because right now I have to restart the machine, boot Linux, mount Windows' data partition, copy the file(s), restart and boot back into Windows.
I had assumed I could use WSL to open and mount the partition and then access my files from there, but it seems to not be possible if the partition is on the same disk as the Windows install.
Is there some other method or workaround? I found Linsk as a possible solution, but it seems to require quite a lot of prerequisites for it to work (virtualization, QEMU, OpenVPN Tap Networking Drivers). Are there less complicated solution I could try or is Linsk the only viable solution for me (dual-boot on the same drive)?

This question is similar to: How can I access volumes encrypted with LUKS/dm-crypt from Windows?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Windows is installed on a disk different from the LUKS partition it wants to access whereas I only have 1 disk drive.

Not really relevant.

Yes it is. Only "offline" disks can be mounted to WSL, Windows and the LUKS partition are on the same disk and therefore can't set the disk to offline and mounted to WSL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#limitations
"* At this time, only entire disks can be attached to WSL 2, meaning that it's not possible to attach only a partition. Concretely, this means that it's not possible to use wsl --mount to read a partition on the boot device, because that device can't be detached from Windows."
The LUKS partition and Windows are on the same disk, therefore that last answer won't work.

You should still be able to use the old LibreCrypt to mount luks partitions in windows. Plus a driver like ext4fsd for whatever filesystem is underneath, and then you can access the files from windows without any virtualization
